# New battery - any special treatment required?

Tags: battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break in a new cell phone battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-break-in-a-new-cell-phone-battery)

Admittedly this could be aimed at any mobile device, but I have a new battery for a HTC sensation. To get the best out of it, does it need any special charge/discharge cycling?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should wipe your battery stats, charge it up to full without turning it on (or without using it, if you have a model that turns on automatically when charging), turn it on & let it discharge all the way, then charge it back to full again in order to recalibrate battery level readings.

How to wipe your battery stats depends on what device you're using and what ROM you have loaded.

Comment: It's a vanilla htc sensation - Vodafone branded android 2.3.3. Is there a way to reset stats on such a device?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know any ways that don't involve rooting.  If you do have root, you could try [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration).